# Node.js Socket.io - How to emit messages to socket rooms within another listener?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm trying to emit messsage to specific rooms, once the "joinedRoom' listener is triggered by the client, the code works fine if I place my code outside the joinedRoom listeners, otherwise it does nothing.

Code:

```
app.get('/room/:room/user/:user', function(req, res){
    var room = {
        username: req.params.user,
        roomname: req.params.room
    };
    res.render('room', room);
});

var users  = {};

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('joinedRoom', function(roomData){
        socket.username = roomData.username;
        socket.room = roomData.roomname;

        console.log("Roomname: " + socket.room);
        console.log("Username: " + socket.username);

        socket.join(socket.room);
        socket.broadcast.to(socket.room).emit('newUser', socket.username);

        socket.on('disconnect', function(){
            socket.broadcast.emit('userLeft', socket.username);
            socket.leave(socket.room);

            console.log('Connection id: ' + socket.id);
        });
    });
});
```

Client code:

```
var socket, roomname, ioRoom;
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');

socket.on('enterRoom', function(roomname){
    console.log("ENTERED ROOM: " + roomname);
});

socket.on('newUser', function(username){
    pushUserName(username);
    pushUserStatus(username, ' has joined the room <br/>')
});

socket.on('newRoom', function(data){
    alert(data)
});

socket.on('userLeft', function(username){
    pushUserStatus(username, ' has left the room <br/>')
})

function pushUserName(username){
    var el = document.getElementById("username");
    el.innerHTML += username + '<br/>';
}

function pushUserStatus(username, message){
    var el = document.getElementById("joined");
    el.innerHTML += username + message;
}
```

Code the emits "joinedRoom" event:

```
doctype html
head
    title Sala #{roomname}

    script(src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js")
    script(type="text/javascript").
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
        var roomData = {
            roomname: '#{roomname}',
            username: '#{username}'
        }
        socket.emit('joinedRoom', roomData);

    script(src="../../../js/room.js")

  body
      p#joined
      h1 Room's name: #{roomname}

      h2 Your nickname: #{username}

      h2 Players:

      p#username.player-row
```

I saw the docs and some sample code and everything seems to be correct (when it comes simply to syntax) am I missing something simple here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to register your disconnect event listener outside of your connection event listener.

Code:

```
app.get('/room/:room/user/:user', function(req, res){
    var room = {
        username: req.params.user,
        roomname: req.params.room
    };
    res.render('room', room);
});

var users  = {};

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('joinedRoom', function(roomData){
        socket.username = roomData.username;
        socket.room = roomData.roomname;

        console.log("Roomname: " + socket.room);
        console.log("Username: " + socket.username);

        socket.join(socket.room);
        socket.broadcast.to(socket.room).emit('newUser', socket.username);
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        // need more logic here
    });
});
```

Comment: Hello @Yod thanks for your help, I did what you recommended but it didn't work, the fun fact is if I remove the joinedRoom listener entirely then it works....

Answer (score 0):

For those who might have a similar problem the code is mostly correct but I was missing this:

Instead of:

```
socket.emit('joinedRoom', roomData);
```

Should be:

```
socket.on('connect', function(){
    socket.emit('joinedRoom', roomData);
})
```

:)